# US to Germany connecting in Dublin - how much time needed to transfer?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, short-connections, dub

Flying from US to Germany via Aer Lingus, both legs, connecting flight is in the same Dublin terminal (2) and arrival is in early morning (6 AM). Is 1.5 hours enough time to get through immigration/customs to the gate? Three passengers, 2 Americans, 1 European. I'm guessing we're okay, since it's not a crazy bustling airport, same airline, early morning, but just want to make sure.

Comment: Thanks to all for the useful information, will post what happened.

Comment: Doc was right, immigration was in Hamburg, the connection was straightforward, we had to take a bus though, which was pretty crowded. Inbound flight left late, about a half hour, maybe a little more, so lots of people coming onto the plane late. There was a special connections doorway. The whole thing was very well logistically organized. We got on the plane before most, probably waited 30 minutes till wheels up. I guess even though the connecting flight was in the same terminal, it was far enough away to merit a bus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this specific connection there is no need to go through immigration, customs or even security in Dublin - you simply follow the "Flight Connections" sign when you land and you will be in the departure area for your connecting flight.

Given this, 1.5 hours is plenty of time, presuming your inbound flight is on time.

If your inbound flight is late, then because you're on a single ticket it'll be the responsibility of the airline to book you on a later flight at no cost to you.

If you're flying the same route on the return then it's a different story. Passengers from Dublin to the US pass through US immigration/customs/security in Dublin before boarding the plane, so you will require additional time to complete those formalities.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what the other answer states, transit at Dublin does involve a special transit immigration check by the Irish INIS.

That said, should this cause you to miss your flight, you will be re-booked onto the next flight, since the trip is in one booking

Comment: There is a documentation check to make sure you are actually making a connection (and have a corresponding boarding pass), but unless I'm mistaken there is no "immigration" check.

Comment: @Doc It's a full passport control booth run by border officers but located in the transit corridor. This concept also exists at OSL and in China, Mauritius and South Africa (AFAIK in Canada as well)